# How to set time display, and add $(hostname)

Tags: raspbian-jessie, raspbian-stretch, gui

I know that in order to modify the time display this is the menu selection:

[image]

and here is my current favorite:

[image]

BUT, when I try to add `$(hostname)` just like it would work in `echo $(hostname)`,

it shows this:

[image]

QUESTION:  How can I make it show the actual hostname?

Comment: When I look at `man strftime`, I see no facility for displaying the hostname. Have you read somewhere that this is supported?

Comment: No, hence the question.  I do know that in bash you can do `echo $(hostname)` to get it.  You can even do `echo "\\`$date +%-I)\\`" to get the hour.  I am hoping there is something similar that will work in this field by invoking a bash command like $(hostname)

Comment: Honestly, I don't know... I would guess that it's not, but I could be wrong. I say that because  everything that's mentioned in the man page is from a datetime-like object. hostname is not. But, if you find a way to do that, I would love to hear of it!

Answer (score 1):

Those `%` codes aren't processed by the shell, they're processed by `date`, and perhaps some other things -- as Seamus observed, they come from the POSIX C command `strftime()`, which almost certainly is in the `date` source code.  The interface for `date` is also specified by POSIX.

> You can even do
>
> ```
>  echo `date +%-I`
> ```
>
> to get the hour.

Yes, although the `echo` is superfluous; `date +%-I` will do the same thing.  The backticks are equivalent to `$()` (capture the output of a command).  When the shell sees that line, it does the capture and passes the output to `echo`.

`echo` and `date` are both standalone executable, although bash has a built-in `echo` command which does the same thing (the standalone `echo` is there for use outside of the shell).

`hostname` is an independent program too.